# Upgrade to Debian testing shows only white noise

Tags: debian, system-installation

I've installed Debian on my desktop, but now all I can see is white noise on my screen.

1. started with a squeeze netinstall
2. updated my `/etc/apt/sources.list` from:

   ```
   # deb http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ squeeze main

   deb http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ squeeze main
   deb-src http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ squeeze main

   deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
   deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main

   # squeeze-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
   deb http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ squeeze-updates main
   deb-src http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ squeeze-updates main
   ```

   to:

   ```
   deb http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
   deb-src http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

   deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
   deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
   ```
3. Run:

   ```
   aptitude update
   aptitude install apt dpkg aptitude
   aptitude full-upgrade
   ```

   The only thing that stood out during the upgrade was the warning that firmware for `r8169` was no longer installed.

During the boot I can see normal text, but - before I need to type my password - my screen only shows white noise.

**Edit:**

- The `/home` directory is coming from a Ubuntu (11.04 upgraded to 11.10).
- I haven't installed X yet. On my first install run (this is currently the third), I tried installing X to "fix" the problem, but that resulted in the same thing (although there was a different noise block for my mouse that I could move around).
- Copied the syslog to [gist-8929da15](https://gist.github.com/8929da15dff60088c7e0)

Comment: Can you get to a text console by hitting alt-F1?

Comment: I haven't install X yet. All TTYs show the same.

Comment: Try booting in single user mode, then.

Comment: If you were previously using X, it was probably trying to come up. Otherwise you would have seen a text console. You could try killing it with Ctrl-Alt-Backspace. Take a look at the logs, and post a suitable snippet if you wish. Are you using  a proprietary module, like Nvidia? If so. check it is being loaded.

Comment: I've copied [/var/log/syslog](https://gist.github.com/8929da15dff60088c7e0)

Comment: Before executing `aptitude full-upgrade` it would be more safe to execute `aptitude safe-upgrade`. Syslog is not very helpful in this case (there are some errors but don't look very critical), try booting in rescue mode and also `cat ~/.xsession-errors` to see if X is failing.

Comment: When booting with the 2.6.32-5 (instead of 3.1.0-1) kernel it works without a problem.